# How to get selected row data from popup Gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, gridview

I have created Following GridView with CheckBox field.CheckBoxes are used to get the Selected(checked) row data when Clicking Submit button.
It works fine without error.

```
<div id="dialog2" style="display:none" >
    <asp:GridView ID="GvSalesItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="sno" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" PageSize="10" AllowPaging="True">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" runat="server" onclick = "checkAll(this);" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" onclick = "Check_Click(this)" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName = "Select" OnClientClick = "return GetSelectedRow(this)" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="sno" HeaderText="Sno" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="itemcode" HeaderText="Item Code" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="itemname" HeaderText="Item Name" />
        </Columns>
    </GridView>
```

C# function for Submit Button

```
protected void btnItemSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GvSalesItems.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvrow.Cells[0].FindControl("chk");
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            int sno = int.Parse(gvrow.Cells[2].Text);
            int invoiceno = Convert.ToInt32(LblInvoiceAuto.Text);
            string itemcode = gvrow.Cells[3].Text;
            string itemname = gvrow.Cells[4].Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(sno,invoiceno, itemcode, itemname);
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to show this GridView in Popup, Hence i am using Following JavaScript function.But, checkbox function is not working now.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=btn3]").click(function () {
            ShowPopup2();
            return false;
        });
    });
    function ShowPopup2() {
        $("#dialog2").dialog({
            title: "Item GridView",
            width: 550,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            modal: true
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: which checkbox function?

Comment: I want to get selected (checked)  row data and store it in DataTable when clicking a button (outside the GridView).my idea works fine when i use Static GridView rather than Popup

Comment: from what I see it should also work fine with a popup.  Note:  make sure `btnItemSave` is also contained within `dialog2` and remove the dialog OK button.  No need to close the dialog as `btnItemSave` is going to cause a postback, effectively closing your dialog.

Comment: Ok sir, i will try and post my result soon.Thank u

Comment: sir i have placed btnItemSave Button inside the Div. But, it does not postback.As follow  </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="btnItemSave" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="btnItemSave_Click" Width="72px" />
    </div>

Comment: You added an `onclick` attribute...don't do that. That is a client side attribute that tells the button to make a call to a javascript function called `btnItemSave_Click`.  Rather, in the designer double click the button and it will take you to the code behind of the server side click handler.

Comment: i tried your suggestion but it does not work again. if i place a button outside the div and trigger the button click using javascript function it working.but, it does not save any row to DataTable, because it shows no row is checked. I have tried with Break Point. I think I need correct javascript function for checkbox changed.can you help me please

Comment: I am using following javascript function to Show the Popup window and trigger the button click event,  function ShowPopup2() {
            $("#dialog2").dialog({
                title: "Item GridView",
                width: 550,
                buttons: {
                    Save: function () {
                        $("[id*=btnItemSave]").click();
                    },
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }

            });
            }
        </script>

Comment: try this in Page_Load in the code behind: `btnItemSave.OnClientClick = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnItemSave, string.Empty);`.  this will generate an asp.net clientside postback.  And still get rid of the dialog OK button.

Comment: Ok sir, i will try morning and post my comment

Comment: Forget what I told you.  The Dialog does somethings that need to be corrected.  I'll post an answer with my trial code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issues Editing a Gridview in a jQuery UI dialog

jquery UI `dialog()` moves the dialog div outside the form.  This makes it impossible to submit changes.  So first we need to reposition it back inside the form after it opens.  And since you want the hidden dialog to keep it's position I added a new div called `dialog_container`, so we have the following:

---

#### Modified .aspx markup

```
    <div id="dialog_container">
      <div id="dialog2" style="display: none">
        <asp:GridView ID="GvSalesItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
           . . .
        </asp:GridView>

        <%-- 
           NOTE: The "OnClick" attribute, when defined in the markup, renders 
                 a submit button that causes a postback to a server side
                 click handler: "protected void btnItemSave_Click(...)".  

                 This is not to be confused with OnClientClick which renders
                 an "onclick" html attribute in order to run a javascript
                 function
          --%>
        <asp:Button ID="btnItemSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="72px"
             OnClick="btnItemSave_Click" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

#### Modified Javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        $("[id*=btn3]").click(function () {
            ShowPopup2();
            return false;
        });
      });

      // temp var to handle repositioning the dialog
      var $dlg = null;

      // Moved dialog options "out of line"
      // Note: no buttons defined
      var dlg_options = {
        title: "Item GridView",
        width: 550,
        modal: true
      };

      function ShowPopup2() {
        //open dialog and save dialog jquery object to $dlg
        $dlg = $("#dialog2").dialog(dlg_options);

        // reposition dialog back inside the form in its container
        $dlg.parent().appendTo($("#dialog_container"));
      }
    </script>
```

Now the submit button within div `dialog2` will work as expected.

---

## Working with UpdatePanels, Modified 2016-12-19

When you introduce an updatePanel with jquery and jqueryui you have to account for partial page updates.  Specifically as it has to do with the jquery ready() event

#### Standard jquery ready event for a full postback:

```
    $(function () {
      $("[id*=btn3]").click(function () {
        ShowPopup2();
        return false;
      });
    });
```

But the above only gets called on the initial call of the page, i.e. when `!Page.IsPostBack()`.  After you do a postback from an UpdatePanel triggered event that ready event doesn't get called and so never "wires up" the `$("[id*=btn3]").click()` event

#### jquery ready event for a full and partial postbacks:

In order to fire the ready event in both PostBack and non PostBack states you must handle the partial page postback.  I use the following construct:

```
    // The standard jquery ready() event
    $( function() {
        MyPage_FullAndPartialPostbackHandler( false, null, null )
    } );

    // The ASP.Net partial page postback endRequest event handler
    // This is the "ready event" for an UpdatePanel partial postback.
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function( sender, args ) {
        MyPage_FullAndPartialPostbackHandler( true, sender, args ); 
    } );

    // Now both "ready" events call this one handler with appropriate
    // parameters to be used as necessary.
    function MyPage_FullAndPartialPostbackHandler( IsPartialPostBack, sender, args ) 
    {
        $("[id*=btn3]").click(function () {
            ShowPopup2();
            return false;
        });
    }
```

The above ensures that the ready event is called for both "full" and partial postbacks

Comment: Thanks a lot it works as i expected. you saved my times.As i am new to programming i have tried several methods to achieve this, finally you full filed my expectations.Once again thanks a lot..

Comment: sir, i want to add the close button in the popup window, it should close the window completely. Because, this javascript function can not close completely when i am using UpdataPanel for the Div.Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to do things a bit differently when you introduce an update Panel.  I'll add the change in my answer.

Comment: Hello sir, i would like to use this jquery to show another popup in the same form, but it does not works.how can i do that.i have created another one Gridview and two Divs like this but,it can not show popup

Comment: There are a number of ways to do that. Either via parameters to the functions so you can determine which dialog to show, or you can create a duplicate set of controls, new button (`btn3a`) that uses it's own JS (`ShowPopup2a()` that references the new dialog and dialog options (`$("#dialog2a").dialog(dlg_options_2a)`.  It's just a matter of how complex you want to make it, parameters versus code duplication

Comment: i have tried as you suggested but i cant achieve this. I have created new components as follows dialog2a,dialog_container2a,btn2a,dlg_options_2a.I did code duplication but still not working.

Comment: Can you update your original post by appending relevant new code and markup to the bottom?

Comment: Ok i will post soon. Before that i need to check it again in another asp project

Comment: Thanks for your fastest reply

Comment: It works nice. now it shows both popup grid view. the problem is arrived because of i have no given on client click in buttons. When i am using single popup it not necessary. Now, i should give It in every button. Thanks @fnostro